# cannot get the link to download win 11 ISO file it seems the link generated but not available to me

Tags: download, iso, windows-11

here is the result screenshot i got when I step through the process of downloading the iso file of win 11 in the official ms website please help me out downloading the file.

it seems the link to the file is successfully generated but i cannot see/get it. I wodered if there is a mistake.[the result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHsR2.png)

Even i tried using different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

click on 64-bit download, this ISO file will start downloading.